# Incorrect Output in mysql split function

Tags: mysql

I have created mysql function to split the string in rows using temporary table, it gives correct in temp table, but not when i call the function it returns 1 as output.
My code is as below

```
  DELIMITER $$



      DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `split`$$

CREATE  FUNCTION `split`(`String` VARCHAR(8000), `Delimiter` CHAR(1))     RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN       
 DECLARE idx INT;       
DECLARE slice VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE result INT DEFAULT 0;    
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;    
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp` (items VARCHAR(8000));
-- set @tmptab = tmp;  
SET idx = 1;  

   label:  WHILE LENGTH(`String`)<1 OR `String` IS NULL DO
      LEAVE label;     
      END WHILE; 
loop_lable: WHILE (idx<>0) DO       

    SET idx = LOCATE(`Delimiter`,`String`);       
    IF (idx<>0)       THEN

        SET slice = LEFT(`String`,idx - 1);       
    ELSE       
        SET slice = `String`;       
     END IF;  
    IF(LENGTH(slice)>0)  THEN
        INSERT INTO tmp(Items) VALUES(slice) ; 
        SET  result = 1;    
     END IF;
    SET `String` = RIGHT(`String`,LENGTH(`String`) - idx);       
    IF LENGTH(`String`) = 0  THEN
     LEAVE loop_lable;
     END IF;      
END WHILE;  
RETURN  result; 

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You do a `RETURN  result;`. So why do you expect something else?

Comment: how can i get correct output..?

Comment: when i call the function SELECT `split`("dada,dad,adad,adad",',') it should split the string in rows